# How to inject css file from a html file while working in django?

Tags: django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm currently working on a django course which probably has older version of Django. My html file contains one css link, which needs to be injected into my code.

My code works fine in browser and I have no errors, but my webpage has no styling in it. 
Also I looked up into various answers here and I followed the steps very carefully, but still I'm not able to figure out what I lack.
I would like to know other methodologies for injecting css as I mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe show your code where you are importing your css?

Comment: we cannot provide a useful solution unless you improve this question. you need to add some code showing exactly what the problem is